# How to store object in mongoose schema?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In node.js I have three variables:

```
var name = 'Peter';
var surname = 'Bloom';
var addresses = [
    {street: 'W Division', city: 'Chicago'},
    {street: 'Beekman', city: 'New York'},
    {street: 'Florence', city: 'Los Angeles'},
];
```

And schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var personSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  name    : String,
  surname : String,
  addresses : ????
});
```

What type and how do I use it in schema? How is the best way for this?

Comment: what you are describing is an array of objects not an object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must create another mongoose schema:

**var address = Schema({
street: String,
city: String});**

And the type of addresses will be **Array< address >**

Answer (score 2):

The Solution to save array is much simple,Please check below code

```
Adv.save({addresses: JSON.stringify(addresses)})
```

Your schema will look like it

```
var personSchema = Schema({
 _id     : Number,
 name    : String,
 surname : String,
 addresses : String,
});
```

Comment: only one problem with this way of storing Schema, Say we wanted to be able to query the address data on here? like for example, get the list of results that hit for the Los Angeles, then we wouldnt be able to query those records

Answer (score 2):

```
//Your Schema is very easy like below and no need to define _id( MongoDB will automatically create _id in hexadecimal string)
var personSchema = Schema({
  name    : String,
  surname : String,
  addresses : [{
    street: String,
    city: String
  }]

var addresses= [
    {street: 'W Division', city: 'Chicago'},
    {street: 'Beekman', city: 'New York'},
    {street: 'Florence', city: 'Los Angeles'}
];
//Saving in Schema
var personData = new personSchema ({
  name:'peter',
  surname:'bloom',
  addresses:addresses  
})
personData.save();
```

Hope this may solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

You are actually storing an array.

```
var personSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  name    : String,
  surname : String,
  addresses : []
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ref in personSchema

```
var personSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number,\n
  name    : String,
  surname : String,
  addresses : [{ref:Adress}]
});

var address = Schema({street: String, city: String});


mongoose.model('PersonSchema', personSchema);
mongoose.model('Adress', adress);
```

'ref' is used to making a reference of address and used in personSchema